# use LESS in webpack and es6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, less, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm following a lecture on [Angular With Webpack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3PNhMk4MWg).
I am trying to add the **less loader** and keep getting an error.

```
 ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../style.less in  D:\projects\dev\webpack-angular-demo/src
 @ ./src/app.js 3:0-24
```

My **webpack.config.js** is :

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry:'./app.js',
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                //create working environment for es6 need to npm i babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 -D
                //https://github.com/babel/babel-loader
                test:/\.js$/,
                exclude:'/node_modules',
                loader:'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }, 
            {
                //take less  convert to css and inject to style tag    need to: npm i css-loader less-loader less  style-loader -D
                //https://github.com/webpack/less-loader
                test:/\.less$/,
                exclude:'/node_modules',
                loader:"style!css!less"
            }           
        ]
    }
};
```

My **app.js** is:

```
import '../style.less';
class Log{
    constructor(){
        console.log("sdfsdf");
    }
}
new Log();
```

Inside the **src** directory i have the app.js , index.html and style.less files.

finally , this is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-angular-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

any idea why i'm getting this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had the exact same problem like you. i managed to solve that with tiny change.

```
path.join(__dirname, 'src')
```

instead of using:

```
__dirname + '/src/
```

now, make sure that your webpack.config.js look like:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
 context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
...
```

and when I import the style.less i used like above

```
import './style.less';
```

Comment: That was it ! thanks a lot. i will try to find the 'why' also. tnx

Answer (score 1):

If all files are in the same directory (`src`), the first line in `app.js` should be:

`import './style.less';`

Comment: applying this fix result with more errors : <br/>ERROR in ./src/style.less
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../node_modules/
css-loader/index.js in D:\projects\dev\webpack-angular-demo/src
 @ ./src/style.less 4:14-116

ERROR in ./src/style.less
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../node_modules/
style-loader/addStyles.js in D:\projects\dev\webpack-angular-demo/src
 @ ./src/style.less 7:13-68

Comment: with two dots the correct loader is used so the exclude rule is working. now , the exclude is not working and the node_modules folder is searched as well . i think....

Comment: If I try to run `webpack-dev-server` with your exact setup and my suggestion, it runs fine. Can you confirm all of the modules are installed / perhaps run `npm install` once more?

Comment: my project tree is : root [ node_modules , package.json , webpack.config.js , src [ app.js , index.html , style.less ] ] . your project tree is the same ? i have tried already **npm install** . I have the same problem with `import config from '../src/config.json' after adding a **json-loader**.